# Vuetify: Style only the last row of a v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to apply a different style to **only the last row** of a `v-data-table`?

To be more specific, by style I mean changing the border and background color.

```
<v-data-table
  disable-sort
  :headers="headers"
  :items="data"
  :item-key="id"
  >
  <template v-slot:item="row">
  <tr :key="row.item.id">
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.field1 }} </td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.field2 }} </td>
  </tr>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a class with the styles on condition:

```
<v-data-table
  disable-sort
  :headers="headers"
  :items="data"
  :item-key="id"
>
  <template v-slot:item="row">
  <tr 
    :key="row.item.id" 
    :class="{'lastRow': data.length>0 && row.item.id==data[data.length-1].item.id}"
  >
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.field1 }} </td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.field2 }} </td>
  </tr>
</v-data-table>
```

```
.lastRow { background-color:'grey'; border: 1px solid black; }
```

In some vuetify themes,  is transparent, so it might be necessary to override it using

```
.lastRow {background-color:rgba(105,105,105,0.3); border: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: It works great for the border, but not the background. The selection logic works great, though, thanks! Is there something in v-data-table that prevents background change?

Comment: @MaloMarrec you are welcome. Try using the updated answer.

Comment: Concerning the condition, I think ``vuetify`` has a better option of getting the ``index`` of the row. You can research more on the topic. If so, you can make ``index==data.length-1``

Comment: @MaloMarrec please mark the answer as the solution if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: It appears that the v-data-table sets transparency to the v-row element. I edited the answer to compensate for that with `background-color:rgba(105,105,105,0.3)`